# Java reference variable declared outside method lives on stack or on heap

Tags: java

```
 class  Test
 {
     int y=10; // defined as part of the class
     Test obj1 =new Test();

 public void function1(){
    int x = 5; // defined locally
   Test obj2=new Test();
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Test obj = new Test();
}
 }
```

we already know the varibale "y" will gon heap and variable x will go on stack But my question is where will the reference variable "obj" which is a reference to test class be sved? on heap or stack?
Also where will the reference variables "obj1" and "obj2" be saved on stack or heap? Ofcourse the object goes to heap but what about reference variables when declared inside function it goes to stack but what about when declared outside function?Confused.Please Help.

Comment: Obj will be on the stack. The actual test object will go in the heap. Any reference created inside a method will go on the stack.

Comment: @TheLostMind what about obj1 sir its declared outside any method so shouldnt reference variable obj1 be on heap along with object?

Comment: I didn't dv but my impression is that the question is of the type that could be easily answered with some study of the Java Language Specification.  Since you are in learning mode, it would be beneficial to begin getting accustomed to that excellent document's organization so you learn where to look for future reference.  This is part of your fundamental education, and you should at least mak an effort at it before asking here.

Comment: @YashaswiBhardwaj - You are getting down votes because your post shows lack of research effort. We expect people to do some research before posting a question.

Comment: @YashaswiBhardwaj - The reference `obj1` will be on the heap and points to an Object that also exists on the heap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `obj1` (the reference) is itself part of an instance of `Test` which was allocated on the heap.  The value pointed to by `obj1` is a *different* instance of `Test`, which is also on the heap.

The only things on the stack are parameters to methods and variables declared inside methods.

Note that your first invocation of `new Test()` will fail due to the recursive infinite loop you've set up.  Each contruction of a new `Test` require the construction of an additional `Test`, ad infinitum.  You'll probably get a StackOverflowError, as method invocations stake up stack space even with no parameters and local variables.